# Automatically draw hidden portions of paths with dashed lines

Tags: rendering, nurbs-surface

This is a follow up to [a question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287665/8425) on [TeX stackexchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

[image]

Is it possible in blender to have an open surface that would render as opaque but the render would show automatically, depending on the position of the camera, the hidden parts of its boundary with dashed lines?

I'm a beginner in blender. Here is a simple blend file reproducing the surface of my original post.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Can do this using [Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html#visibility) and choose how to render Hidden edges. The [zipped sample file](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/File:HiddenCreaseEdgeMark.zip) renders the image below.

[image]

Select [dashed line style](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_style/strokes.html#dashed-line) from the Freestyle Line Style Panel in Render Layers Properties.

Quick proof of concept on your file.

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks (+1)! I now have to read carefully the docs!