# How do you create a dashed circle in blender?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

How would you create a dashed circle in blender with an empty circle object?

I want something that looks sort of like this:

[image]

Related: [How do you create a dashed line in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165292/how-to-create-a-dashed-line)

Comment: give an image or something please

Comment: I got it from the link you provided. So you want something like this right?
................................

Comment: I want something like - - - - - - - - (except in a circle)

Comment: Create a mesh circle object, enter edit mode, select all in edge mode, use checker de-select from selection menu, delete only edges faces.

Comment: what do you mean by "empty circle"? Ratt gives a solution, another one would be to use the Array modifier and the Curve modifier with a bezier circle as Object

Comment: Thanks everybody for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple and in the link which you provided. Add a circle object, go to the bottom left, click on the triangle thingy, and set fill type from nothing to N-Gon, or if you prefer nothing, I don't mind, that is your choice. Then rotate the circle 90 degrees. Then, add an array modifier and set the values to this:

[image]

You can change the count to how much you like depending on the number of dots you want. I just set it to 15.

Here's the rendered result:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: so what did you mean

Comment: Could you help me make a dashed circle, not a dotted line? Thanks.